# os x terminal -remove files older than x days

Tags: macos, terminal, script

trying to create a scripts that deletes files older than X days. It seemed straight forward enough but all files seem to be getting removed?

```
find /Volumes/Groups/Projects/530_BFAMI/test/ -ctime +30 -print -exec rm {} \;
```

any ideas welcome!?

Also would be good to print file information for matches as maybe my dates are misleading in finder?

Comment: agh apologies. Is working. Can i have multiple parameters? Ie include a size? -ctime +30 AND -size +10000000c

Comment: There's a *significant* difference between `ctime` and `mtime` and in most cases people mean to use `mtime` (the time the contents of the file last changed) and not `ctime` (the time the inode-related information for the file changed). Very rare to see `ctime` used this way, so I mention this as a caution to you OP.

Answer (score 20):

Never suggesting `-exec rm ...`.

`rm` is simply too dangerous command. Always dry-run first. IMHO it is better using this:

```
find /Volumes/Groups/Projects/530_BFAMI/test/ -ctime +30 -print0 | xargs -0 -n1
```

this will show the dry-run and only when you satisfied you can add the `rm` to the end

```
find /Volumes/Groups/Projects/530_BFAMI/test/ -ctime +30 -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

If you start using this `piped to xargs` version, you can always add more filters, like:

```
find /some/where -mtime +3d -print0 | grep -ziE '\.(jpg|png|gif)$' | xargs -0 rm
```

and similar (more) powerful combinations.

Comment: This answer should have been accepted. Thanks, was looking for just this.

Comment: What is -ctime +30 ? Is it 30 days before? or 30 minutes before files. Please explain.

Comment: @ToughGuy  If no units are specified, this primary evaluates to true if the difference between the time of last
             change of file status information and the time find was started, rounded up to the next full 24-hour
             period, is n 24-hour periods. - aka: days

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question asked in your comment: You can join separate criteria just by listing them, one after the other. If you prefer, you can use `-a` or `-and` in between them, but these are redundant. You can also use `-o` or `-or` for the OR operator, and you can use parentheses – which must be quoted to protect them from the shell, as in `\(` and `\)` for grouping.

For the full details, run: `man find`

Answer (score 2):

It is considered dangerous to use -exec rm without first ls. You should probably check that first. Reverse check is also a good hint to tell you if your timing is correct.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -30d -exec ls -latr {} \;
```

OR

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -atime -30d -exec ls -latr {} \;
```

1. Constrain your find result. Make sure what you explicitly ask for.
2. Compare to see if the opposite result is what actually has been excluded from your original command.
3. Probably `-mtime` or `-atime` are more appropraite but again compare the result and see if they are actually what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `find . -ctime +30 | xargs rm -r 2> /dev/null`

For some reason, this runs rm twice. So I just redirect the errors to the black hole `/dev/null`

Enjoy.